# Email sent using intent going to outbox Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-emulator

I am developing app which sends email for that I am using intent as follows

```
Intent emailI = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"aaaaa@gmail.com","bbbbbbb@gmail.com"});
    emailI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Email Testing");
    emailI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"dear sir/mam find my mail");
    emailI.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailI, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

after running this code new message is generated in outbox of Email account I have used to send mail.

I have given following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I am running app in emulator and I have created account in emulator which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try android.content.intenT.ACTION_SEND

final Intent emailIntent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);